# $\underline{\nabla} \cdot \underline{A} $ in polar coordinates.

Tags: vector-analysis

I have just shown that in polar coordinates we have,
$$\underline{\nabla} = \frac{ \partial }{ \partial r} \space \underline{\hat{r}}+\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \space \underline{\hat{\theta}}$$

Now assume that $\underline{A} = A_1 \underline{\hat{r}} + A_2 \underline{\hat{\theta}}$. I wish to find what  $\underline{\nabla} \cdot \underline{A} $ would be given this information.

I figured it would be $ \frac{\partial}{\partial r}(A_1)+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(A_2)$ but this not the case the actual result is,
$$\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} ( r A_1 )+\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(A_2)$$ 
I'm unsure how this follows and I was hoping someone would be able to shed some light on where I am going wrong, thanks!

Comment: pde tag? Doesn't look like a pde to me ! :P

Comment: True I changed it. This was asked as part of my PDE class.

Comment: I think your notation may be incorrect. In particular, $A\cdot \nabla$ is emphatically not "the actual result" that you quote. In particular, the derivative operator is to the right of $A$ in $A\cdot \nabla$, not to the left, so it should not act on $A$. When dealing with differential operators like del, you should note that the product rule typically means that $A \cdot \nabla \neq \nabla \cdot A$. The left hand side is an operator and the right hand side is a number.

Comment: I changed it, you're right it should be the other way around.

Comment: @JustinStevenson: Keep in mind that for cylindrical coordinates, $\mathbf{a_r}$ and $\mathbf{a_{\theta}}$  are not constants. As an example, for the unit vector in the direction of $\mathbf{r}$, $\mathbf{a_r} = \cos\theta{\mathbf{i}} + \sin\theta{\mathbf{j}}$, which is a function of $\theta$. This is different from Cartesian coordinates where the unit vectors, $\mathbf{i, j, k}$ are constants.

Comment: So how would I take the dot product then? Am i not able to just do the usual procedure because of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An important point to note is to that in cylindrical coordinates, the unit vectors can be specified as:
$$\begin {align}
\mathbf{a_r}&=\cos\theta{\mathbf{i}} + \sin\theta{\mathbf{j}} \\
\mathbf{a_{\theta}}&=-\sin\theta{\mathbf{i}} + \cos\theta{\mathbf{j}} \\
\mathbf{a_z}&=\mathbf{k}
\end{align}  \nonumber $$

Of course, you can refer to the literature on how to derive these unit vectors.

Now (and specific to your question), given that $\mathbf{A} = A_1\mathbf{a_r}+A_2\mathbf{a_{\theta}}$ then (with the component of $\mathbf{a_k}$ identically $0$), the Divergence of the vector $\mathbf{A}$ can be calculated as:
$$ \begin {align}
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} &= \left(\frac{\partial }{\partial{r}}\mathbf{a_r} +  \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial{\theta}}\mathbf{a_{\theta}}   \right) \cdot \left(A_1\mathbf{a_r}+A_2\mathbf{a_{\theta}} \right) \\
&= \mathbf{a_r}\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial{r}} \left(A_1 \mathbf{a_r}\right) + \mathbf{a_r}\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial{r}} \left(A_2 \mathbf{a_{\theta}}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{r}\mathbf{a_{\theta}}\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial{\theta}} \left(A_1 \mathbf{a_r}\right) +  \frac{1}{r}\mathbf{a_{\theta}}\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial{\theta}} \left(A_2 \mathbf{a_{\theta}}\right)
\end{align}  \nonumber 
$$

$$
\begin {align}
\Rightarrow \nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} &= \mathbf{a_r} \cdot \left(A_1  \frac{\partial }{\partial{r}}\mathbf{a_r} +  \mathbf{a_r}\frac{\partial }{\partial{r}}A_1 \right) \\
                                                     &= \mathbf{a_r} \cdot \left(A_2  \frac{\partial }{\partial{r}}\mathbf{a_{\theta}} +  \mathbf{a_{\theta}}\frac{\partial }{\partial{r}}A_2 \right) \\
                                                     &=  \frac{1}{r}\mathbf{a_{\theta}} \cdot \left(A_1  \frac{\partial }{\partial{\theta}}\mathbf{a_r} +  \mathbf{a_r}\frac{\partial }{\partial{\theta}}A_1 \right) \\
                                                    &=  \frac{1}{r}\mathbf{a_{\theta}} \cdot \left(A_2  \frac{\partial }{\partial{\theta}}\mathbf{a_{\theta}} +  \mathbf{a_{\theta}}\frac{\partial }{\partial{\theta}}A_2 \right) 
\end{align}  \nonumber 
$$

Again, since $$\mathbf{a_r} =\cos\theta{\mathbf{i}} + \sin\theta{\mathbf{j}} $$ this implies that $\frac{\partial }{\partial{r}}\mathbf{a_r} = 0$ and $\frac{\partial }{\partial{\theta}}\mathbf{a_r} = -\sin\theta{\mathbf{i}} + \cos\theta{\mathbf{j}} = \mathbf{a_{\theta}}$.

Also, from
$$ \mathbf{a_{\theta}} =-\sin\theta{\mathbf{i}} + \cos\theta{\mathbf{j}} $$
this implies that
$\frac{\partial }{\partial{r}}\mathbf{a_{\theta}} = 0$ and $\frac{\partial }{\partial{\theta}}\mathbf{a_{\theta}} = -\cos\theta{\mathbf{i}} - \sin\theta{\mathbf{j}} = -\mathbf{a_r}$.

Substituting and simplifying gives:
$$
\begin {align}
\mathbf{a_r} \cdot \left(A_1  \frac{\partial }{\partial{r}}\mathbf{a_r} +  \mathbf{a_r}\frac{\partial }{\partial{r}}A_1 \right)  &= \frac{\partial }{\partial{r}}A_1 \\
\mathbf{a_r} \cdot \left(A_2  \frac{\partial }{\partial{r}}\mathbf{a_{\theta}} +  \mathbf{a_{\theta}}\frac{\partial }{\partial{r}}A_2 \right) &= 0 \\
 \frac{1}{r}\mathbf{a_{\theta}} \cdot \left(A_1  \frac{\partial }{\partial{\theta}}\mathbf{a_r} +  \mathbf{a_r}\frac{\partial }{\partial{\theta}}A_1 \right) &= \frac{1}{r}A_1 \\
\frac{1}{r}\mathbf{a_{\theta}} \cdot \left(A_2  \frac{\partial }{\partial{\theta}}\mathbf{a_{\theta}} +  \mathbf{a_{\theta}}\frac{\partial }{\partial{\theta}}A_2 \right)  &= \frac{\partial }{\partial{\theta}}A_2
\end{align}  \nonumber 
$$

Therefore:
$$ \nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} = \frac{\partial }{\partial{r}}A_1 + \frac{1}{r}A_1 +  \frac{\partial }{\partial{\theta}}A_2 $$
Now to put in a form that agrees with the given answer, notice that: 
$$ \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial }{\partial{r}}\left(rA_1\right) =  \frac{1}{r} \left(r\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}A_1 + A_1\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}r \right) =\frac{\partial }{\partial{r}}A_1 + \frac{1}{r}A_1  
$$

Summary: 
$$
\begin {align}
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} &= \frac{\partial }{\partial{r}}A_1 + \frac{1}{r}A_1 +  \frac{\partial }{\partial{\theta}}A_2 \\
                                   &= \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial }{\partial{r}}\left(rA_1\right) + \frac{\partial }{\partial{\theta}}A_2
\end{align}  \nonumber 
$$

Comment: Just to clarify when doing a dot product you take the whole expansion as if you were doing binomial multiplication? But in Cartesian coordinates we have that $\hat{i} \cdot \hat{j} =0$ and so the middle terms cancel leaving the usual formula that I was thinking always applies?

Comment: @JustinStevenson: 1) Yes, in this case, the dot product is taken just as $\left(\mathbf{x} +  \mathbf{y}\right) \cdot \left(\mathbf{w} +  \mathbf{v}\right)$ . 2) Also, as an example, keep in mind that $\mathbf{a_r}\cdot\mathbf{a_{\theta}}=0$ Check it!